# MalformedInputException with Files.readAllLines()

Tags: java, file, java-8

I was iterating over some files, 5328 to be precise. These files are average XML files with 60-200 lines max. They are first filtered through a simple method *isXmlSourceFile* that parse the path.

```
    Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/me/development/projects/myproject"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
            .filter(V3TestsGenerator::isXmlTestSourceFile)
            .filter(V3TestsGenerator::fileContainsXmlTag)
```

The big question is for the second filter, especially the method fileContainsXmlTag. For each file I wanted to detect if a pattern was contained at least once among the lines of it:

```
private static boolean fileContainsXmlTag(Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.readAllLines(path).stream().anyMatch(line -> PATTERN.matcher(line).find());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

For some files I get then this exception

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3205)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3242)
```

But when I use FileUtiles.readLines() instead of Files.readAllLines everything is getting well.

It's a curiosity question so if someone as a clue of what's going on, it's with pleasure.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The method [`Files.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) assumes that the file you are reading is encoded in UTF-8.

If you get this exception, then the file you are reading is most likely encoded using a different character encoding than UTF-8.

Find out what character encoding is used, and use the other [`readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) method, that allows you to specify the character encoding.

For example, if the files are encoded in ISO-8859-1:

```
return Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).stream()... // etc.
```

The method `FileUtiles.readLines()` (where does that come from?) probably assumes something else (it probably assumes the files are in the default character encoding of your system, which is something else than UTF-8).

Comment: I have the same problem - I believe this is related to CR LF.
FileUtils.readLines(new File(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) worked fine for me where Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) did not.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: It's odd, I got this message with a file that was UTF-8 encoded according to Notepad++. So I don't agree with this answer. I suspect @Yost777 may have the answer. I am probably reading a text file created on a Unix platform on a Windows machine and getting this issue. In my case though I have this syntax: `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));`

Comment: ISO-8859-1 did fix it for me though. Seems to neutralise that issue.

Answer (score 1):

FileUtils.readLines from Apache Commons IO uses java.io.InputStreamReader.

InputStreamReader uses a CharsetDecoder to read bytes, but it changes
onMalformedInput and onUnmappableCharacter from the default REPORT (meaning
throw an exception) to REPLACE (meaning insert some replacement character).

Files.readAllLines however leaves the default behavior of the CharsetDecoder and
therefore throws an exception if a malformed or unmappable byte sequence is
read. There is a hint to this hidden in the documentation of readAllLines:

```
 * @throws  IOException
 *          if an I/O error occurs reading from the file or a malformed or
 *          unmappable byte sequence is read
```

Files.readAllLines is part of "NIO", Java's new approach at IO. NIO quite
consistently throws an exception on invalid input, while the "old" classes
replace invalid input. However you can change NIO's behavior by using the
methods that accept a CharsetDecoder and pass a CharsetDecoder that you have configured according to your needs.